# Motorola SBG6580 cable modem into Bridge mode on Bright House Networks does not work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, bridge

I tried placing a Motorola SBG6580 into bridge mode but when I connected via Ethernet to it, I was not able to access the internet or get an IP, I had to statically assign myself a 192.168.100.x IP to access the modem. (I have a diferent modem at home and I can plug my laptop into it and get a public IP address and start browsing the web just fine)

I've read guides like:
http://ecstasyrealty.com/motorola-sbg685.html
http://fascinated.fm/post/2379188731/getting-a-motorola-sbg6580-into-bridge-mode-on

but none of these seem to work. When you switch to bridge mode the options limit themselves so you have no access to DHCP or even the passthru option that I could notice.

The router also failed to pull an IPv4 address automatically under it't WAN and Internet settings. (at home I have a pfSense box and it pulled the IPv4 settings automatically just fine)

What else could I try to get this to switch over?

Because it's COAX cable do I need to clone the MAC address over to the router so the ISP can properly find a device to assign IP information too?

Comment: Why do you want it in bridge mode?

Comment: Some modems will only work with a single MAC address that has been registered in the modem.

    When you change the connected device from the router to your PC (which have different MAC addresses) you may have to reset your modem to recognise the new MAC address (and repeat when you change back again).

Comment: Some ISPs register the MAC address within their own network. This MAC adress is used the "register" the internet connection when it is first connected (often by a "terms and conditions" page which you agree to on first connection).

    If this is the case then you may have to call your ISP to additional MAC addresses to your account.